# Spring MVC Redirect Attribute Messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I am having some issues while displaying messages after I have successfully, or unsuccessfully performed some type of CRUD operation (CREATE, DELETE, etc). I have attempted to use Redirect Flash Attributes, although I have found no luck with these and I cannot get the message displaying at all. For example I have declared something like this within my Controller method:

```
public String DeleteAction(Model model, Object object, @RequestParam int id, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
   // Method logic
   object.delete(id);
   attributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Object has been removed successfully.");
   return "index"; // View resolver redirect
}
```

That is an example of my function within one of my controllers where I declare the flash attribute to be binded to the view. I call the flash attribute like this within the .jsp `${success}`, although I still cannot get it to display. Is there anything I am missing which is not enabling this to work?

Comment: why you're not returning "redirect:"+"index"?
usage of flash attribute is as it should be.

Comment: Because I thought that you can just return "view" and let the view resolver handle the the rest, although that could be the problem considering that it is not a redirect just a mapping to a new view. However, I have tried `return "redirect: index"` and it also did not work, so I am still left unclear why. Unless I do actually need to add the '+' symbol there, is that right?

Comment: @Maff answer posted, if it helps you

Comment: no you dont need the +, Maff. Can you try omitting the space if you really have it? I mean 'return "redirect:index"; '

do redirection works in any case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A specialization of the `Model` interface that `controllers` can use to select attributes for a redirect scenario. Since the intent of adding `redirect attributes` is very explicit -- i.e. to be used for a `redirect URL`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String DeleteAction(Model model, Object object, @RequestParam int id RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    object.delete(id);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Object has been removed successfully.");
    return "redirect:" + "index";
}
```

Comment: I will try this code segment and provide you some feedback accordingly. Can I conditionally check against the flash attribute object "success" utilising a `c:if` statement and check whether it is null?

Comment: confirmed that this is working for me now. I am still to try this without supplying the '+' symbol, and just have `return "redirect: index";`

Comment: value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET - SHOULD BE POST!!! Get is only for idempotent actions! Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: Copied without attribution from https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html